# Is ASP Membership Provider password and salt machine or OS specific?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have some code in a EF Code First initializer that is grabbing the Membership Provider (ASP Universal Provider) and seeding some users.  I know that isn't necessarily normal scenario but it has been working great in local dev.  When pushing to Azure I sometimes see it not work.  I see the records created in the Membership tables created, but when I log in with the password it doesn't match.  Updating the salt and password with values from my local also don't seem to work.  Is there something specific about the machine or OS for the salt/password generation or validation?  It doesn't make sense because that would mess up any farm scenario, just looking for any help on why I might see something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you set the machine key explicitly, Membership Provider uses that key to encrypt the password.

So you need to have same machine key in all web.config files.

Comment: I think I recall doing this once a long time ago.  Thanks for the reminder.  I'm going to try setting it per this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations) and see if I don't run into the issue.  Marking as answer for now.  Thanks